# Pick up the value from the three excel sheet and show in another sheet using macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel macros. I am struck here.. I have three worksheet say A B and C.. in these sheets i have particular cell.. what i need to do is, i want to count how many cells of same kind is there in worksheet A B and C and should display in another worksheet using macros.. For Eg:

```
in sheet A i have a cell A1
In sheet B i have a cell B1
In Sheet C I have a cel C1
```

So here in three sheets i have three values A1 B1 and C1. I want to add count these and add and show in another sheet using macros. like eg
How many cells are there : A1 B1 and C1 i.e 3.

can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you're trying to count or add? I can see this going different ways.

- If you're trying to add different cells and you know that they will not change, then you can simply set, say, a fourth one the result through VBA:

  ```
  Sheet4.Range("A1") = Sheet1.Range("A1").value + ... SheetN.Range("A1").value
  ```
- If you're trying to count cells, then you probably want to identify which of them are empty and which aren't. In that case, you can test for them like this:

  ```
  if Sheet1.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
      MsgBox("Not Empty")
  Else
      MsgBox("Empty")
  ```

But to be honest, in a situation like yours I would find it less cumbersome to just insert an Excel formula in my end cell:

```
=COUNT(SHEET1!$A$1, SHEET2!$A$1, ...)
```

The result could even be sent through a     `MsgBox` or formatted through a `=CONCATENATE()` function.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are asking. but you can acces the properties of cells in diferenst sheets this way.

in this example you will set the value of cell A1 in sheet A to hello A1, cell A2 in sheet B to hello A2, cell A3 in sheet C to hello A3"

```
A.Range("A1").Value = "Hello A1"
B.Range("A2").Value = "Hello A2"
C.Range("A3").Value = "Hello A3"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thansk for the above and sorry that I confused you.. I will say in simple words. As above there are three cells with value in three different sheet i.e Hello A1 , Hello A2 and Hello A3. I just want to count these cells and should display in another excel sheet like we have three cells in different sheet so total will be 3.I Hope its clear now?